# Google Earth Engine exported TIFF file cell size in ArcGIS

Tags: google-earth-engine, arcgis-pro, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-1

I set the scale of my image to 10 when exporting from GEE. When I open the raster in ArcGIS Pro I get a cell size of 8.983152841195213E-05 instead of 10. Is there any way to make it 10 x 10 cell size when exporting?

Here is the snippet of the export section:

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: water_img_2,
  description: 'Water_img_2',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 10,
  region: roi,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  folder: 'GEE_Feb',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
})
```

Comment: The image is in decimal degrees. There is no exact conversion to Cartesian units available unless you export into UTM or an Equal Area projection, which will result in resampling.

Comment: The Image was initially in EPSG:32646, but when I used ee.Image.Median(), it got converted to 'EPSG:4326'. Is there any way to not get converted to that projection?

Comment: Probably, but different Question. You'll need to rewrite it.

Comment: Did you try exporting with crs:'EPSG:32646'? The default "EPSG:4326" projection that you see when you print your image after performing median() is just there to remind you to specify an unambiguous way to generate the output you want. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#the-default-projection

Comment: Yes, I have exported with crs: 'EPSG:32646' too, I am confused about whether it might cause any issues or not